# order php associative nested array by date key

Tags: php, arrays, usort, array-multisort

I want to order the dates inside each [dataPartenza] of this associative array in ascending order, I found many answers about indexed arrays but not something similar.. the problem here is that the dates are not value of the array but the keys itself, so I cannot apply the usort methods that I found on the other answers.

**PHP:**

```php
[destinazione] => Array(
[Corfù] => Array(
  [dataPartenza] => Array(
    [2021 - 07 - 16] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 365.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 50.00
          )
        )[comfort] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 395.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 60.00
          )
        )
      )
    )[2021 - 07 - 23] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 365.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 50.00
          )
        )[comfort] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 395.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 60.00
          )
        )
      )
    )[2021 - 08 - 06] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 365.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 50.00
          )
        )[comfort] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 385.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 60.00
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)[Zante] => Array(
  [dataPartenza] => Array(
    [2021 - 07 - 17] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => 5[prezzo] => 395.00
          )[01 | bilocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 4[prezzo] => 415.00
          )[02 | studios] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 405.00
          )[03 | studios] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 425.00
          )
        )
      )
    )[2021 - 07 - 24] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 395.00
          )[01 | bilocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 4[prezzo] => 425.00
          )[02 | studio] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 415.00
          )[03 | studio] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 445.00
          )
        )
      )
    )[2021 - 07 - 31] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 395.00
          )[01 | bilocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 4[prezzo] => 425.00
          )[02 | studio] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 415.00
          )[03 | studio] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 445.00
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)[Pag] => Array(
  [dataPartenza] => Array(
    [2021 - 07 - 18] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 274.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 30.00
          )[02 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 50.00
          )
        )
      )
    )[2021 - 07 - 25] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 274.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 30.00
          )[02 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 50.00
          )
        )
      )
    )[2021 - 08 - 01] => Array(
      [soldout] => [sistemazione] => Array(
        [basic] => Array(
          [00 | quota base] => Array(
            [capienza] => N / S[prezzo] => 274.00
          )[01 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 3[prezzo] => 30.00
          )[02 | supplemento monolocale] => Array(
            [capienza] => 2[prezzo] => 50.00
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
))
```

as suggested I'm adding a json_encode version more compact too

**JSON:**

````json
    {
       "destinazione":{
          "Corfù":{
             "dataPartenza":{
                "2021-07-16":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"365.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"50.00"
                         }
                      },
                      "comfort":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"395.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"60.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "2021-07-23":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"365.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"50.00"
                         }
                      },
                      "comfort":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"395.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"60.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "2021-08-06":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"365.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"50.00"
                         }
                      },
                      "comfort":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"385.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"60.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "Zante":{
             "dataPartenza":{
                "2021-07-17":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"5",
                            "prezzo":"395.00"
                         },
                         "01|bilocale":{
                            "capienza":"4",
                            "prezzo":"415.00"
                         },
                         "02|studios":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"405.00"
                         },
                         "03|studios":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"425.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "2021-07-24":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"395.00"
                         },
                         "01|bilocale ":{
                            "capienza":"4",
                            "prezzo":"425.00"
                         },
                         "02|studio":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"415.00"
                         },
                         "03|studio":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"445.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "2021-07-31":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"395.00"
                         },
                         "01|bilocale":{
                            "capienza":"4",
                            "prezzo":"425.00"
                         },
                         "02|studio":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"415.00"
                         },
                         "03|studio":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"445.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "Pag":{
             "dataPartenza":{
                "2021-07-18":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"274.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"30.00"
                         },
                         "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"50.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "2021-07-25":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"274.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"30.00"
                         },
                         "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"50.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "2021-08-01":{
                   "soldout":false,
                   "sistemazione":{
                      "basic":{
                         "00|quota base":{
                            "capienza":"N/S",
                            "prezzo":"274.00"
                         },
                         "01|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"3",
                            "prezzo":"30.00"
                         },
                         "02|supplemento monolocale":{
                            "capienza":"2",
                            "prezzo":"50.00"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }

I'm putting here the snippet for the solution provided by @Anton this is working perfectly with usort and regular sort flag for yyyy-mm-dd formatted value:

**PHP:**
```php
<?php
    $data = '{"destinazione":{"Corfù":{"dataPartenza":{"2021-07-24":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}},"2021-07-23":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}},"2021-01-06":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"365.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"50.00"}},"comfort":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"385.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"60.00"}}}}}},"Zante":{"dataPartenza":{"2021-07-17":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"5","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"415.00"},"02|studios":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"405.00"},"03|studios":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"425.00"}}}},"2021-07-24":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale ":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"425.00"},"02|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"415.00"},"03|studio":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"445.00"}}}},"2021-07-31":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"395.00"},"01|bilocale":{"capienza":"4","prezzo":"425.00"},"02|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"415.00"},"03|studio":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"445.00"}}}}}},"Pag":{"dataPartenza":{"2021-07-18":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"274.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"30.00"},"02|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}},"2021-08-01":{"soldout":false,"sistemazione":{"basic":{"00|quota base":{"capienza":"N/S","prezzo":"274.00"},"01|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"3","prezzo":"30.00"},"02|supplemento monolocale":{"capienza":"2","prezzo":"50.00"}}}}}}}}';
    $input = json_decode($data, true);
    
    $output = $input;
    foreach ($input['destinazione'] as $city_name => $city_data) {
        $dataPartenza = $city_data['dataPartenza'];
        ksort($dataPartenza);
        $output['destinazione'][$city_name]['dataPartenza'] = $dataPartenza;
    }
    
    echo "\n\nOUTPUT: " . json_encode($output);
````

**EDIT:** Cleared array in a more readable format and added json version

Comment: [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)?

Comment: Array in your example is unreadable. Use `json_encode` for example to make it more compact

Comment: @Anton I added a json version too

Comment: @silvered.dragon Good, so now we can see that your dates already sorted asc. Why do you need to sort them one more time?

Comment: @Anton this json is coming from a dynamic extensible form that can grow in time. So now are ordered because I have just filled the form by myself in this asc way. If I will add more dates I want they to be in asc order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is already in comments: `ksort`. Here is example: [click](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d85b344fc086e20fb86682224d37c5cea6f1b17).

So I take array, ksort it, put back to result:

```php
// get 'dataPartenza'
$dataPartenza = $city_data['dataPartenza'];
// sort it
ksort($dataPartenza);
// put to result
$output['destinazione'][$city_name]['dataPartenza'] = $dataPartenza;
```